# Prevent restarting app when switching theme in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-theme

I have a problem with my app that when I toggling the system theme it restart the entire app to the main fragment, How can I prevent this that when switching to dark mode or light it wont restart the entire app.

Comment: It also does this if the user rotates the device, changes the system language, or connects a physical keyboard, etc. It's how Android is designed. You can elect not to have your Activity restarted under certain configuration changes, but it's a lot of hassle to do properly and not recommended by the documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange

Comment: @Tenfour04 I already resolve the rotating by adding something in manifest.

Comment: Fix your app state restore to not launch its main fragment unconditionally but only when needed.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, and I spend a lot of time trying to find a solution. Then, I found this article on Medium:

[Applying dark mode without recreating your app](https://proandroiddev.com/daynight-applying-dark-mode-without-recreating-your-app-c8a62d51092d)

You need to specify uiMode on your Activity and handle the theme state changes by yourself.

```
<activity
android:name=".MyActivity"
android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```